# What is this method supposed to do?

Tags: java

```
public static int f(int n) {
    return 2*f(n-2) + f(n-3);
}
```

For my ICS class, I was asked to explain what the method is supposed to do and how to fix it. I have never seen this kind of sequence method before, so I have no idea where to start.

Comment: It's *recursion* and it's missing the *base cases*. Do those terms mean anything to you? I am guessing you've been recently taught them. If you've learned about those concepts, you need to apply them here. If not, you should talk to your teacher; we're not going to be able to explain them adequately on this site.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive call. Inside function f(int n) it calls itself again and again. You should add a termination statement so that the recursion stops at some point. Otherwise it will cause a stack over flow. 
eg :

```
public static int f(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    return 2*f(n-2) + f(n-3);
}
```